# Combine Networks in different towns

Tags: networking

In a theoretical question if I wanted to combine 2 similar buisness networks in different towns (within 40miles)

What is the networking technology that would be required?

Comment: your answer is simple, VPN between layer 3 networking devices

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Seb's answer a little:

- Basic VPN: Cheapest, usually plenty for light to medium usage
- Leased ISP VPN: ISPs will provide a transparent VPN link between sites without public routing. This is more expensive but as its not "over the top" it comes with some traffic prioritization and enterprise SLAs that buying your own endpoints won't get.
- Wireless: Over 10KM its impractical, would require multiple repeating points
- Leased fibre: Most expensive but you can rent dark fibre between A and B and run whatever you like on it. This is what data centre operators would do.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN(Virtual Private Network) would do the job. VPN gateways will be needed.

Comment: I really like this answer.  "WAN" may also be a good term to look up, but VPN is likely to provide an inexpensive solution for you.